# Problems with playstation plus and save files backup

Tags: ps3, playstation-plus

I recently purchased playstation plus using a prepaid card (a prepaid subscription not a top up one). I entered the code and everything works perfectly. I downloaded this months PSplus games on my device. The problem that I have is I am trying to setup the auto-update and save file backup feature but it keeps asking me to join playstation plus. Why is this happening? I am using the same PSN account that I redeemed the code from.

Comment: You should contact Sony customer support for help with this question. If it let you download the PSN+ free games then the other PSN+ features should be active. You may need their help in resolving the problem.

Comment: Forgot about this question. It has been answered by me. I will answer it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save file backup with playstation plus took around two weeks to get activated and it was everything ok.